# Apply coefficients from n degree polynomial to formula

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I use a sklearn `LinearRegression()`estimator, with 5 variables

```
['feat1', 'feat2', 'feat3', 'feat4', 'feat5']
```

In order to predict a continuous value.

Estimator returns the list of coefficient values and the bias:

```
linear = LinearRegression()
print(linear.coef_)
print(linear.intercept_)

[ 0.18799409 -0.05406106 -0.01327966 -0.13348129 -0.00614054]
-0.011064865422734674
```

Then, given the fact I have each feature as variables, I can hardcode the coefficients into a linear formula and estimate my values, like so:

```
val = ((0.18799409*feat1) - (0.05406106*feat2) - (0.01327966*feat3) - (0.13348129*feat4) - (0.00614054*feat5)) -0.011064865422734674
```

---

Now lets say I use a polynomial regression of degree 2, using a pipeline, and by printing:

```
model = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler',StandardScaler()),
    ('polynomial_features', PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree, include_bias=False)), 
    ('linear_regression', LinearRegression())])

#fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(model['linear_regression'].coef_)
print(model['linear_regression'].intercept_)
```

I get:

```
[ 7.06524186e-01 -2.98605001e-02 -4.67175212e-02 -4.86890790e-01
 -1.06320101e-02 -2.77958604e-03 -3.38253025e-04 -7.80563090e-03
  4.51356888e-03  8.32036733e-03  3.57638244e-02 -2.16446849e-02
 -7.92169287e-02  3.36809467e-02 -6.60531497e-03  2.16613331e-02
  2.10097993e-02  3.49970303e-02 -3.02970698e-02 -7.81462599e-03]
0.011042927069084668
```

---

How do I transform the formula above in order to calculate `val` from regression, with values from `.coef_` and `.intercept_`, using array indexing instead of hardcoding the values, for *any* 'n' degree ?

Is there any `scipy` or `numpy` method suited for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that polynomial regression is just an extended case of linear regression, thus all we need to do is transform our input data consistently. For any N we can use the `PolynomialFeatures` from `sklearn.preprocessing.` From using dummy data, we can see how this would work:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
#set parameters
X = np.stack([np.arange(i,i+10) for i in range(5)]).T
Y = np.random.randn(10)*10+3
N = 2

poly_reg=PolynomialFeatures(degree=N,include_bias=False)
X_poly=poly_reg.fit_transform(X) 
#print(X[0],X_poly[0]) #to check parameters, note that it includes the y intercept as an input of 1

poly = LinearRegression().fit(X_poly, Y)
```

And thus, we can get the coef_ the way you were doing before, and simply perform a matrix multiplication to get the regressed value.

```
new_dat = poly_reg.transform(np.arange(2,2+10,2)[None]) #5 new datapoints 
np.testing.assert_array_equal(poly.predict(new_dat),new_dat @ poly.coef_ + poly.intercept_)
```

**----EDIT----**

In case you cannot use the transform for PolynomialFeatures, it's just a iterated combination loop to generate the data from your list of features.

```
new_feats = np.array([feat1,feat2,feat3,feat4,feat5])

from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
def gen_poly_feats(x,N):
    #this function returns all unique groupings (w/ replacement) of the indices into the array x for use in polynomial regression.
    return np.concatenate([[np.product(x[np.array(i)]) for i in list(combinations_with_replacement(range(len(x)), n))] for n in range(1,N+1)])[None]

new_feats_poly = gen_poly_feats(new_feats,N)
# just to be sure that this matches...
np.testing.assert_array_equal(new_feats_poly,poly_reg.transform(new_feats[None]))
#then we can use the above linear regression model to predict the new data
val = new_feats_poly @ poly.coef_ + poly.intercept_
```

Comment: `val` correspond to future values, not available at the time of fitting the regression. is that what you mean by `new_dat`?

Comment: `new_dat` is just some new data, of the same size/type as the training data in `X`.

Comment: I got a bit confused, because I actually use a Pipeline(), which makes values a bit awkward to be extracted either from preprocessor or estimators. . Maybe you you adapt tour answer I'll award you with a bounty. I've edited the question to make it more complete

Comment: Edited my answer, although I'm not 100% sure why you wouldn't just be able to use the sklearn `PolynomialFeatures` function. Either way, hope it works for you now.

Comment: Added another edit because my previous wouldn't work for N other than 2.

Comment: perfect! double thanks